# Facebook Graph API query for updates in the last 24 horus

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph API to query for data; however, I only want the data updated in the 24 hours or something like that.

For example,

```
get('https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/me/adaccounts?fields=name,id&last_updated=onedayago')
```

I can't seem to find anything regarding this in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of `&until=timestamp` and `&since=timestamp`. They take a [UNIX timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) as argument. `&since=1502213821` would be since now (amount of seconds since 01-01-1970). Since your question is about relative time, I suggest you use your programming language to generate the UNIX timestamp according to your preferred timerange.

In PHP that would be `time() - (24 * 60 * 60)` for 24 hours ago.

Comment: it seems that the time stamp doesn't apply do what I'm trying to do. Thanks anyways.